# How do I limit new users from accessing the GUI application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, active-directory, group-policy

Existing setups has Login's are connected to Active directory where new user's are  created.

My task is to limit the new users from accessing the apps.

I would like to seclude them to use predefined apps I need them to use
(for eg: firefox,chrome,other app).

Is there any application that I could manage or any other way I could acheive this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I am using Ubuntu 18 for now, but I am not restricted to use only ubuntu versions or other linux flavours. If the solution is available for centos, I am ready to migrate.

This is new project, so I have no fear of breaking setup or things.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux systems, you can control the permissions of the binary that opens the GUI application directly. Let's say I want to restrict users to access Firefox on Ubuntu... If I type the command:

```
$ whereis firefox
firefox: /usr/bin/firefox /usr/lib/firefox /etc/firefox /usr/share/man/man1/firefox.1.gz
```

Its binary file is located on `/usr/bin/firefox` and we can see its permissions with `ls - lh`:

```
$ ls -lh /usr/bin/firefox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 out 31 05:44 /usr/bin/firefox -> ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh
```

Here we see that its permission is `rwxrwxrwx`. That means `rwx` for the user **root**, `rwx` for the group **root** and `rwx` for **other users**. As `r` stands for reading permission, `w` stands for writing permission and `x` stands for executing permission.

In this example, you should create a specific group to manage it and give execution and write permissions on its binary file. You can do it as following:

```
sudo addgroup newgroup
sudo addgroup myusernamea newgroup
sudo addgroup myusernameb newgroup
sudo addgroup myusernamec newgroup
sudo chmod 750 /usr/bin/firefox
sudo chown root:newgroup /usr/bin/firefox
```

Basically, I've created a new group called `newgroup`, added the users that I want to this group, taken out the "other users" permissions with `chmod 750` and finally made my Firefox file accessible for the group `newgroup`.

Comment: chown would be a *terrible* idea. This means that user (or, with 770, the group) would have access to edit that binary. Don't chown it or give group write permission.

Comment: @MikeyB I understand your concern... But isn't this issue completely solved in the moment that you put a 750 permission? Most binary files on my computer are 755 by default... So I really see no bigger issues in using `chown` and giving the group only reading and execution permissions... Do you have any alternative solution besides using `chown` on the file and changing its group permission?

Comment: When you used `chown` to change the ownership for the binary, the user is then allowed to make changes to that binary which compromises security. With a group mode of `770`, anyone in the group is able to change the binary, again compromising security. The owner must be left as `root` and group *write* permissions should not be given.

Comment: @MikeyB I completely understand your concern about the 770 permission and you're right about that... But your comment sounds like there's still something wrong with my answer and that's not true. This solution is completely acceptable in the moment that we use `750` and change the file's group permission, even users who are included in the group will not be capable of changing the binary file or rewriting its permissions...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `selinux`/`apparmor` profiles to limit access for certain groups to ONLY the applications they need.

The advantage of doing it this way is that users will be restricted to *only* what you allow.

The creation of those can be particularly complex, so depending on how *tightly* you need to lock things down, you may not need to go this far.

For example https://serverfault.com/a/993498/2101 is probably a good first step, but be sure to implement other methods in parallel (e.g. mounting `/home` as `noexec` so users can't run their own applications out of there) for increased security.

Answer (score 0):

Using SSSD with AD as its identity provider, you can use the Active Directory user groups and users as Linux groups and users. See [here (Ubuntu)](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html) and [here (RHEL)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/sssd-ad)

Once this is done, you can restrict access to a specific executable to a certain system group as explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/8842/64489). 
Just make sure that old users are in the AD group and new users are not added automatically to it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement the setup

Comment: How does sssd + MSAD have any bearing here? Its just another means of provisioning a user account. The control mechanism doesn't care what's sitting behind the nameservice - the same mechanism will work for local accounts, NIS+ (if anyone is still using that), LDAP accounts....